# Mold is growing on my cheese, what is common practice?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, cheese, food-preservation, mold

I love cheese and I am always buying and trying new types. Because of this, my cheese stash starts to grow faster than I can eat all of it. Sometimes mold starts to grow around the outside before I get to it, particularly the cheddar.

I practice good storage techniques to no avail, still the mold eventually shows up.  So when this happens, I just trim the mold off and move on, but some of my friends think this is "so gross" and I should just throw it away.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

I cut it off also. Don't tell your friends you do it. I have heard you can freeze some cheeses, but I think it looses flavor with freezing. flavor is after all why you buy and eat cheese. have more cheese tasting parties.

Comment: +1 for cheese tasting parties to use up the cheese faster :D

Comment: I have *always* trimmed the moldy bits off my cheddar, and have so far survived 2.82e10 kilometers of travel around the sun without obvious cheese-related ill health.

Comment: So long as it's properly wrapped, freezing does not affect the flavor - but if you are not going to melt it, it does affect the texture in most cases. If melted, I doubt you could tell which was frozen in a true double-blind trial (ie, without clues) against unfrozen cheese.